# How to create a java class using efficient way to work with strings

Tags: java

A java class named dna  having 3 variables:

- a String to store sequence
- an int to store number of invalid characters in the string
- an int to store the number of valid characters in the string.

One constructor String that takes dna sequence (a c g t) as an argument. 
How can I check the argument and count how many characters are invalid and how many are valid and store the count in proper variables.**I can't use regular expression here**, so I am lost. How can I USE String's **charAt** method and **if** statement here.

Please help....

Comment: Can you provide us with any code?

Comment: What have you tried? I think nothing. This won't help in getting good answers.

Comment: according to you which are valid and un valid

Comment: I imagine values that aren't part of the genetic sequence @NikhilAgrawal (acgt)

Comment: I am not able to understand What is this genetic sequence

Comment: @Nikhil genenetic sequence is a,c,g and t anything else will be invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one of the many ways of doing it:

Maintain a constant in your class

```
private static final String bases = "atcg";
```

And these other fields to store values

```
String dna;
Integer numValid;
Integer numInvalid;
```

And use them like this in the constructor

```
public DNA(String dna) {
    this.dna = dna;
    for (char c : dna.toCharArray()) {
        if (bases.indexOf(c) < 0) {
            numInvalid++;
        } else {
            numValid++;
        }
    }
}
```

The advantage you get with such an implementation is that even if the list of valid characters changes you need not modify the `if` conditions, which might look bad if the list is vary large.

Comment: If you want uppercase characters included in the valid characters list, you can initialize `bases` as "atcgATCG".

Comment: ,thank you very much for your suggestion, using this method I can keep a count of valid and invalid but don't understand how can I store  these in proper variables.

Answer (score 2):

Use a foreach loop to cycle through each value. If the given character does not match either a OR c OR g OR T (I'm giving you clues there), then you can increase the respective variables. Without Regex, this is the most efficient method, because you have to check each and every letter in the sequence to know with certainty that your values accurately reflect the DNA string.

```
for(char c : dna)
{
    if(c == ..) // Compare against preset values.
    {
        // Update valid count.
    }
    else
    {
        // Update invalid count.
    }
}
```

That's about as generous as I'm going to be, because you need to develop these basic concepts yourself.

Comment: Also, since the sequence is stored in a variable, he could count only the invalid characters, as the valid characters are complementary to the invalid, relative to the sequence's `length`.